# Warning: #1292 Incorrect datetime error when using DATE_ADD()

Tags: mysql, mariadb, date

Doing this works fine:

`SELECT * FROM table WHERE foo < '2021-01-09 00:00:00'`

But this one:

`SELECT * FROM table WHERE DATE_ADD('foo', INTERVAL 5 DAY) < '2021-01-09 00:00:00'`

results in

`Warning: #1292 Incorrect datetime value: 'foo'`

What could possibly be causing this?

(MariaDB 10.4.17)

Comment: The problem is that 2020 is not over.  The correct value for `2021-01-09` is `2020-12-40`.

Comment: @RickJames What do you mean?

Comment: Just joking about how bad 2020 was and how the trauma has not finished, especially in the US.

Comment: @RickJames Whew and yeah..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You try to add to the string `'foo'` 5 days.

Use backticks for column names

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE DATE_ADD(`foo`, INTERVAL 5 DAY) < '2021-01-09 00:00:00'
```

Comment: Why not just `foo`?

Comment: foo is only a placeholder for the real column name, which we don't know. so to be on the save side, it is better to use backticks. But the basic problem, that the user added single quotes and mysql interprets these a stimg, which causes the problem and he has to use backticks instead of the single quotes

Comment: I can't believe it's only that. Thanks!

Comment: @nbk, In the first example foo is used and works. Reason for the string in the second example is unclear, but excessive use of quotes whether needed or not should IMO be discouraged.